# How do I test a simple function in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am new to testing. I am trying to use jest to test 2 functions in my App.js folder. I am trying to add the test to the App.test.js folder. When I run npm test, it finds the default 'renders without crashing' and my test. The default test of course passes, but my test fails and jest says 
`ReferenceError: parentFinder is not defined`. I have the App.js folder imported so I am not sure why it is undefined. Shouldn't it find the function that is to be tested in the App.js file?

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Input from './components/PageWrapper/Input';
import Output from './components/PageWrapper/Output';
import PageHeader from './components/PageWrapper/PageHeader';
import ResetInputButton from './components/PageWrapper/ValidateButton';
import ValidateButton from './components/PageWrapper/ValidateButton';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputData: "",
      outputData:""
    }
  }

  change = e => {
   this.setState({inputData: e.target.value})
   // console.log("e.target.value")
  }

  parentFinder = (data,obj) => {
    let z = 0;
    while (data[z] != null){
      var found = data[z].find((element) => {
        if (element.id === obj.parent_id){
          return element
        }
      });
      if(found != null){
        found.children.push(obj)
      }
      z += 1;
    }
  }

  validationHandler = e => {
    if(this.state.inputData !== "") {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.state.inputData)
      var i = 0;
    while (data[i] != null){
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
      if (data[i][j].parent_id != null){
      this.parentFinder(data,data[i][j])
      }
     }
    i += 1;
   }
   this.setState({outputData:JSON.stringify(data[0],null,5)})
  } else {
    alert("Please enter some data!")
  }
 }

 resetHandler = (e) => {
   this.setState({inputData:""})
   this.setState({outputData:""})
 } 

  render() { 
    return (  
      <div className="wrapper">
        <PageHeader />
        <Input name="inputData" value={this.state.inputData} onChange={this.change} placeholder={'Paste JSON Here'}/>
        <div className="buttonWrapper">
          <ValidateButton title={'Validate'} onClick={this.validationHandler}/> 
          <ResetInputButton title={'Reset Input'} onClick={this.resetHandler}/>
        </div> 
          <Output type="text" value={this.state.outputData}> </Output>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});



test('parentFinder returns null', () => {
  expect(parentFinder(0,obj)).toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: `parentFinder` it is not declared anywhere in your `App.test.js`. Also, `parentFinder` is a method on your App component. You need an instance of your App component in order to get that.

Comment: So I need to write that method in a function form in the App.test.js and then test it?

Comment: Look into the [test renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html); hopefully, that should clear some things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use enzyme(https://airbnb.io/enzyme) to get an instance of the component. The code will be like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

test('parentFinder returns null', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.instance().parentFinder(0,obj)).toBeNull();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`parentFinder` and `obj` not declared anywhere in your test file and they aren't defined globally so you'll receive a "not defined" error.

Based on your example, I'm assuming you mean these:

```
parentFinder = (data,obj) => { // <---- this?
    let z = 0;
    ...
```

If that's the case, `obj` is referring to the element being passed into your `App.parentFinder` method (i.e. the new `div` being created). Since `parentFinder` is a method on your `App` component you'll need to get an instance of your `App`. I recommend using [Test Renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html).

You can accomplish this by doing something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('parentFinder returns null', () => {
  // have the TestRenderer create your App
  const app = TestRenderer.create(<App />);

  // to get the mounted app component instance
  const appInstance = app.getInstance();

  // not sure what you mean by 0,obj in your example
  // but you would pass in your "data"/"obj" values here
  const result = appInstance.parentFinder();
});
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.